# SQL Merge Columns and Sum

Tags: sql, case, aggregate-functions, sumifs

I have a table that looks similiar to this:

```
11/16     C     10
11/16     B     12
11/16     B     2
11/17     A     7
11/17     B     5
11/17     B     5
11/17     A     18
```

My goal is for the table to complete this function:

```
11/16   C     10
11/16   B     14
11/17   A      7
11/17   B     10
11/17   A     18
```

--I've tried CASE/ WHEN & IIF, Can anyone lend some insight?

Comment: This looks like it needs a gaps/islands type solution, however you're missing a key ordering column from your data.

Comment: Looks like sum() and group by functions.. where is the point?

Comment: At a glance, it looks like a `group by` but (11/17, A) appears twice in expected outcome.